# Storing the preferred font-size in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website with the option to change font-size. Every time when you refresh the page though, the font-size you selected returns to the original font-size. The code below shows the html and JavaScript code for how this function works:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
let btn = buttons.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for (var i = 0; i <btn.length; i++){
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    let current = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked');
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("clicked", "");
    this.className += " clicked";
  })
}
```

```css
:root {
  --secondary-color: #4978ff;
}

.sec .buttons {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sec .buttons .btn {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #ddd;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sec .buttons .btn.clicked {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
}

.sec .buttons .btn:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.sec .buttons .btn:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="buttons">
          <span class="btn clicked" onclick="document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = '1em'">A</span>
          <span class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = '1.25em'">A</span>
          <span class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = '1.75em'">A</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text" id="text">
          <h3>i'm an h3</h3>
          <p>i'm a paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I was wondering if it was possible to store the chosen font-size in the localStorage so that it stays the same after you refresh the page?

Comment: You can store the font size in local storage, in a cookie, on the server, or wherever you can think of to put it. It won't have any effect unless you also write some code to retrieve that value and apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by creating a function that changes the `fontSize` and add it on the `LocalStorage` every time a person clicks on it.

After that you can use the `window.onload()` to always check, when the page loads, if there is any `fontSize` on the `LocalStorage` and set it if there is.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<section class="sec">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="buttons">
      <span class="btn clicked" onclick="changeFontSize('1em')">A</span>
      <span class="btn" onclick="changeFontSize('1.25em')">A</span>
      <span class="btn" onclick="changeFontSize('1.75em')">A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text" id="text">
      <h3>i'm an h3</h3>
      <p>i'm a paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const btn = buttons.querySelectorAll('.btn');

window.onload = function() {
  const fontSize = localStorage.getItem('fontSize');
  if (fontSize) {
    document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = fontSize;
  }
}

function changeFontSize(size) {
  localStorage.setItem('fontSize', size);
  document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = size;
}

for(let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    let current = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked');
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("clicked", "");
    this.className += " clicked";
  })
}
```

---

Upgraded Version

**HTML**

```
<section class="sec">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="buttons" role="group" aria-label="Change font size">
      <button class="btn" id="fnt-1em" onclick="changeFontSize('1em')">A</button>
      <button class="btn" id="fnt-1.25em" onclick="changeFontSize('1.25em')">A</button>
      <button class="btn" id="fnt-1.75em" onclick="changeFontSize('1.75em')">A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="text" id="text">
      <h3>i'm an h3</h3>
      <p>i'm a paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const buttonIds = ['fnt-1em', 'fnt-1.25em', 'fnt-1.75em'];

window.onload = function() {
  const fontSize = localStorage.getItem('fontSize');
  if (fontSize) {
    document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = fontSize;
    addClickedClassToButton(fontSize);
  } else {
    changeFontSize('1em'); // set default size
  }
}

function changeFontSize(size) {
  localStorage.setItem('fontSize', size);
  document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = size;
  addClickedClassToButton(size);
}

function addClickedClassToButton(size) {
   const current = document.querySelector('.clicked');
   if(current) {
    current.classList.remove('clicked');
   }
   document.getElementById(`fnt-${size}`).classList.add('clicked');
}
```

Comment: It seems like there are no reassignments to the variables, so you could use `const` instead of `let` for them.

Comment: @SeojinKim, you're right, thanks for the best practice, if you see anything wrong there's no problem by me on editing it :)

Comment: It works for the most part. The font size changes and it stays the same when you restart the page. But all of the buttons are grey and none of them are blue anymore. They also dont turn blue after you click them. In the localStorage there is also the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: document.body.className.add is not a function
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (script.js:46:29)". Is there a way to fix that?